# How to replace strings in StringFormat in WPF Binding

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I need to replace a `,` with `,\n`(New Line) in my string
i want to do it on ClientSide in `StringFormat`

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this via a `StringFormat` binding operation, as that doesn't support replacement, only composition of inputs.

You really have two options - expose a new property on your VM that has the replaced value, and bind to that, or use an `IValueConverter` to handle the replacement.

A value converter could look like:

```
public class AddNewlineConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string original = Convert.ToString(value);
        return original.Replace(",", ",\n");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplemnentedException();
    }
}
```

You'd then use this in your binding.  You could add a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AddNewlineConverter x:Key="addNewLineConv" />
</Window.Resources>
```

In your binding, you'd change this to:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
      Text="{Binding Path=Address, Converter={StaticResource addNewLineConv}}"
      Grid.RowSpan="3" />
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to do that

Comment: @KrishnaThota It's up there.

Comment: Careful: `NotImplemnentedException` => `NotImplementedException`