# WPF ListVIew Grouping name

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Im very new to WPF and i am working with ListView and Grouping.

What im trying to achieve is to group items by certain type but display a different name on the ListView header. This will allow me to have 2 different group types with the same name

Heres my code so far

```
   //.....Populate dummy items in a loop
   items.Add(new Beds() { Name = "Bed " + counter, Type = i.ToString() ,  TypeName = "Test Name" });
   //....

   lvBeds.ItemsSource = items;

   CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvBeds.Items);
   PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Type");
   view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

XAML

```
   <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding TypeName}" Background="Gray" Height="35"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

I want to map the ListView Header TextBlock Text to "TypeName" while keeping the grouping to "Type". Is that possible?

> **Edit:** I solved this by using IValueConverter to handle the replacement of binding name string.

[How to replace strings in StringFormat in WPF Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369615/how-to-replace-strings-in-stringformat-in-wpf-binding)

Comment: Awesome! So whats your problem?

Comment: I want to map the ListView Header TextBlock Text to "TypeName" while keeping the grouping to "Type". Is that possible?

Comment: Looks like you've set it up correctly. Is it not working?

Comment: @JoelLucsy unfortunately the header's text is empty

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in your output window when you run it in debug?

Comment: @JoelLucsy yes i get this error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TypeName' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionViewGroupInternal' (HashCode=34168754)'. BindingExpression:Path=TypeName; DataItem='CollectionViewGroupInternal' (HashCode=34168754); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

I solved this by using IValueConverter to handle the replacement of binding name string.

[How to replace strings in StringFormat in WPF Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369615/how-to-replace-strings-in-stringformat-in-wpf-binding)