# String format of string stored int?

Tags: c#, wpf, string

For reasons I have to have `int` and `decimal` stored as a string. The values can be entered like this, `1234` or like this `1234.00` , but **REMEMBER** they are `strings`

But, I am having issues with dsplaying the formatting the value in a datagrid column.

This obviously does not work, `"{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}}"`, but does work for a `decimal` value.

I have tried all sorts of the usual formatting ,but I can't solve this issue.

I am trying to format the value like this,

When the `string` value is this `1234.00`, have it formatted and display like this:

> 1234

Not like this:

> 1234.00

But if the `string` value like this,

> 1234.45

Have it display like this:

> 1234.45

How do I go about formatting a `string` to display the way I need?

Comment: simply " string formattedstring = inputstring.replace(".00","")

Comment: @Graffito, in WPF, how should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) with a conversion like:

```
public class IntDecConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(Object value, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo CultureInfo)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that a `.` can lead to a wrong conversion - in this case replace the `.` with a `,` by using

```
return System.Convert.ToDecimal(((string)value).Replace(".", ",")).ToString();
```

as conversion.

Create a resource of the converter

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntDecConverter x:Key="intDecConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it like:

```
"{Binding Value, Converter={staticResource intDecConverter}}"
```

Comment: @KyloRen: Also refer to this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369615/how-to-replace-strings-in-stringformat-in-wpf-binding)

Comment: `Convert` method returns an error , where am I supposed to place this?

Comment: You have to create a converter class like shown in the link of @KyloRen - I've added the rest of the class to the answer.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, I did, but I still get an error, `no return type`

Comment: Check the current code of the answer - it's now a complete and working class.

Comment: This error, `Cannot resolve ToDecimal`  , I already have an `IValueConverter` class with a different name, will this cause issues?

Comment: My mistake sorry - use System.Convert.ToDecimal - code is changed!

Comment: OK, I have everything up and running , but the converter does not do its job?????? Error, `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.` Using this line `return Convert.ToDecimal(((string)value).Replace(".", ",")).ToString();`

Comment: looks like your value is no string like you described in your question.

Comment: My bad, I placed the converter in the wrong datagrid. But I get a `throw new NotSupportedException()` when editing the datagrid. Why is that?

Comment: The converter is only one way but you can replace throw new NotImplementedException(); with return value; ... this sould do the trick - I changed the code.

Comment: OK, that works, but all the null values are populated with `0`. If the value is null I want nothing showing if possible. And I should thank you , as you have done a great job helping me thus far.

Comment: You can change the code of the converter whatever you want. Just add a null check like if (value == null) return ""; else return ...

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, I don't know how to do that?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, figured that out, but now it won't allow me to enter decimal values in the column.

Comment: I am going to mark this solved, but it still is not allowing me to enter decimals. THanks for the help.

Comment: I figured out what is going on. Property changed is not allowing the the decimal point as this 1234. is not a valid number. Property changed acts on every keystroke which is why this is not working. I posted the work around in my question.

Comment: Due to this question I asked, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343578/is-posting-an-solution-in-a-question-bad-practice/343579#343579 , I am posting as an answer. Again , thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for people who may stumble on this thread I will post the solution I came up with .So with the help of those people in the comments and @Fruchtzwerg. To see where the bulk of this code comes from see [@Fruchtzwerg's answer here in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176643/6283475)

I was having an issue where the `DataGrid` would not allow to have decimal point entered in the `DataGrid` column, this is due I believe to `PropertyChanged` in the binding.

So the work around was this.

```
public class IntDecConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(Object value, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value == null) return value;
        char[] characters = value.ToString().ToCharArray();
        if (characters[characters.Length - 1].ToString() != ".")
        {
            System.Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.